# How to move an object in the aframe scene by pinching?

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I wrote a custom component based on the [hand-tracking-controls](https://aframe.io/docs/1.4.0/components/hand-tracking-controls.html#:%7E:text=Use%20hand%2Dtracking%2Dcontrols%20to,applications%20requiring%20multiple%20input%20methods.) component from [aframe](https://aframe.io/) library to move the object by pinching it in the scene.

The idea is to listen to the **pinchmoved** event emitted by the entity **leftHand** to move the object. The code for my component can be found below:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('pinch-to-move', {
      init: function() {
        var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
        var trackedEl = sceneEl.querySelectorAll('a-entity')[2];
        this.trackedEl = trackedEl;
        var targetEl = sceneEl.querySelectorAll('a-gltf-model')[0];
        this.targetEl = targetEl;
        targetEl.setAttribute('pinchable', {pinchDistance: 0.05})
        this.localPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
        trackedEl.addEventListener('pinchmoved', this.onPinchMoved);
        this.onPinchMoved = this.onPinchMoved.bind(this);
      },
      
      onPinchMoved: function(evt) {
        var evtDetail = this.evtDetail;
        var localPosition = this.localPosition;
        localPosition.copy(evt.detail.position);
        this.targetEl.object3D.updateMatrixWorld();
        this.targetEl.object3D.worldToLocal(localPosition);
        this.targetEl.object3D.position.x, this.targetEl.object3D.position.y, this.targetEl.object3D.position.z = localPosition.x, localPosition.y, localPosition.z;
        evtDetail.value = (this.targetEl.object3D.position.x, targetEl.object3D.position.y, this.targetEl.object3D.position.z);
        this.targetEl.emit('positionchanged', evtDetail);
        this.trackedEl.emit('pinchmoved');
      }
    });
```

Please note:

1. targetEl is the object to be moved by pinching.
2. trackedEl is the leftHand entity which uses the hand-tracking-controls and emits the **pinchmoved** events.

Lastly, I believe that the problem lies in this line:

```
this.targetEl.object3D.updateMatrixWorld();
```

because the updateMatrixWorld methods doesn't work.

Full code can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/adwait3301/qov10s29/2289/)

I'll be thankful if anybody can propose a solution.

I created breakpoints in my code and tried console.log method to print the output of every line, which gave this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'object3D')
    at <anonymous>:1:28
    at ?editor_console=true:977:28
```

I was able to fix this error by adding

```
this.targetEl = targetEl
```

to the code above.